# Variable length Lookbehinds RegEx don't works in Python

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I want extract the text between ':' and '|' characters, but in second and third data there are a space after the ':'

The intput:

```
Referencia:22726| Referencia Cliente Ak: 233726 | Referencia histórica: 256726 | Suelo | AGOLADA (Pontevedra) -  CARPAZO O PE#A LONJA [EXTRACT]
Referencia:39766| Referencia Cliente Ak: 39767 | Referencia histórica: 39768 | Garaje | MOJACAR (Almería) -  URB.VILLA MIRADOR DEL MAR - MOD. # [EXTRACT]
Referencia:397A5| Referencia Cliente Ak: 397B5 | Referencia histórica: 397C5 | Garaje | MOJACAR (Almería) -  VILLA MIRADOR DEL MAR-MODULO #-PLAZA 4 [EXTRACT]
Referencia:AA39803| Referencia Cliente Ak: P_39803 | Referencia histórica: 200_39803 | Garaje | MOJACAR (Almería) -  VILLA MIRADOR DEL MAR - MODULO [EXTRACT]
```

Output desired:

```
22776
233726
256726
39766
39767
39768
397A5
397B5
397C5
AA39803
P_39803
200_39803
```

My first pattern: `(?<=:)(\w{5,12})`
This matches only the first column.

My second pattern: `(?<=:\s)(\w{5,12})`
This matches the second and third columns

So I believed that my third pattern was the correct one: `(?<=:\s?)(\w{5,12})`  That pattern don't works.

Comment: You can use the `regex` module, which supports variable lengths in lookaheads and lookbehinds. It is planned to replace the standard `re` module, they say. You can install it with Pip. (`pip install regex`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a lookbehind can't be variable length in python. A way to solve this:

```
(?:(?<=:\s)|(?<=:))(\w{5,12})
```

But since you use a capturing group, a lookbehind is useless:

```
:\s?(\w{5,12})
```

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I didn't know that a lookbehind can't be variable length in python. I imagine that neither a lookahead.  But, is it thereby only in python or in other languages too.

Comment: a lookahead can be variable length.

Comment: With .net you can use a variable length lookbehind. Java allows to use this quantifier `{n,m}` and PHP allows alternations.

Comment: That new solution is more clean.  Why a lookahead can be variable length but not either lookbehind?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer about this, as you can see limitations are different between regex engines. People says:"Since a regex engine works from left to right, it is hard to implement a variable length lookbehind." (to repeat three times before sleeping)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `?` character in the Lookbehind move the `\s` to the matches

```
(?<=:)(\s?\w{5,12})
```

Comment: Thanks, elegant solution!